# SONAR V3.6 - Unit Test

Tags: sonarqube

I am running sonar for C# .NET from a cruise control and would like to break the build when unit tests fail. Is this a property on SONAR?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sonar is a reporting tool.  What is the actual build tool you are using for your .NET build?  That's where you should be looking to fail the build.  For example, Maven is the build tool for Java.  Maven fails the build on unit test failures.  Sonar simply reports they happened.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the Build Breaker plugin: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin